# How to correctly arrange elements by the right indexes in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have a problem. I wanted to write a function that would compare 2 sheets and if they are equal, put them on the same position, otherwise put any handicap sign on that position, such as "-".

I was thinking something like this

```
let l1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
let l2 = ["a", "d", "c"]

(l1', l2') = myFunc l1 l2

l1' == ["a", "b", "c", "-"]
l2' == ["a", "-", "c", "d"]
```

I just don't understand what the algorithm should be, that's the point, maybe I could implement it in Haskell, but I think it would be very ugly

Comment: I'd suggest to start with `l3 = zip l1 l2`. From `l3` you can get which elements differs. Also, notice that `l1'` is always `l1 ++ list_of_-`. Hope it helps

Comment: What should be the result for e.g. `myFunc ["a","b","c"] ["b","c","a"]`? I don't think the task is well-specified.

Comment: "Minimum distance" between the two lists is generally done with [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), which is similar to the algorithm used by the library Daniel's answer recommends. However, neither the `Diff` tool nore Levenshtein's algorithm will reorder elements to put `d` at the end like in your input. Can you explain what logic you used to decide that `d` needed to go to the end? Because to an algorithm, `d` is just a random thing in List 2 that's not in List 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Diff](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Diff-0.4.1/docs/Data-Algorithm-Diff.html) package for this. Example:

```
Data.Algorithm.Diff> getDiff "abc" "adc"
[Both 'a' 'a',First 'b',Second 'd',Both 'c' 'c']
```